# Request Timeout when calling Google-APIs inside a Google-Cloud-Run Instance

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Google-Cloud-Run instance which is deployed using the following script.

```
gcloud run deploy <name-of-cloud-run> \
    --image us-<region>-docker.pkg.dev/<artifact-location> \
    --region <region> \
    --service-account <service-account> \
    --concurrency 50 \
    --memory 1024Mi \
    --min-instances 0 \
    --max-instances 1 \
    --port 5000 \
    --timeout 1800 \
    --env-vars-file .env.yaml \
    --add-cloudsql-instances <cloud-sql-connection-string> \
    --project <project>
```

This Google-Cloud-Run is responsible to carry out a certain long-running task and log special-entries in case specific errors or events are encountered. This Cloud-Run also publishes a PubSub message when the process is finished.

I am using Google-Cloud-Python-Libraries for achieving both of the achieving both the tasks ( Cloud-Logging and PubSub message publishing ). Yet in both cases I encounter the same error

`Deadline of 60.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: 504 Deadline Exceeded`

Dockerfile for the underlying image

```
# Using python slim-buster
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Setting the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Setting Shell
SHELL [ "/bin/bash" , "-c" ]

# Updating System
RUN apt-get -y update 

# Installing Requirements
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app


ENTRYPOINT [ "gunicorn", "main:app" , "--worker-class", "gevent", "--workers", "8", "--max-requests", "10000", "--timeout", "1800" ]
CMD [ "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000" ]
```

What could be going wrong here ?

Earlier deployments done using similar scripts did not yield this error and this is the first time. I am encountering this error for the first time.

AS per this answer for the Query : [call to external API is getting blocked on Google Cloud Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971862/call-to-external-api-is-getting-blocked-on-google-cloud-run)

It suggests that the external API is at fault, but in my case even the external API call is to Google itself.

Comment: It's not Cloud Run which is in timeout, but the function that it invokes. Can you share your code to understand more what your Cloud Run service do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when switching to `gevent` workers with `gunicorn`. Looks like the gRPC library or something in the Google Python SDK is not fully compatible with the monkeypatching.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution, so had to stick with the sync workers – the `eventlet` ones didn't even get this far.